# Date Time Picker Comparison not displaying values

Tags: c#, mysql, datetimepicker

In my MySQL database, I am using a DATETIME type to log events. The format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

I am trying to use a Windows Form to display events from a particular range. However, I am not receiving any values with my query. I tried a simple select * and that worked, but not when I tried to use parameters. This is what I have thus far. I know I am very close, just missing something small, I suspect:

```cs
String query = "SELECT Device FROM log WHERE Stamp >= @p_StartDate AND STAMP <= @p_EndDate;
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, myConnection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_StartDate", fromDate.Value); // name of dateTimePicker
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_EndDate", endDate.Value); // name of dateTimePicker2
OdbcDataAdapter adp = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
DataSet set  = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(set);
dataGridView1.DataSource = set.Tables[0];
```

My Date Time Pickers have a Custom Format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss as well so the DateTime should match up but they don't seem to, for some reason.

Comment: What are the values of _fromDate_ and _endDate_? Are they the same date?

Comment: By the way, the _p_EndDate_ parameter placeholder in your query doesn't have the _@_ used when you add the parameter. Is this a typo?

Comment: No, they're never the same date. They are just user inputs. Once I select the finalize button it will trigger the query. And yes, just a typo.

Comment: `OdbcCommand` doesn't support named parameters, I believe.  Try changing your parameters in the query string to question marks:  `SELECT Device FROM log WHERE Stamp >= ? AND STAMP <= ?`

Comment: That was it, thank you.